# Dump all values of input outputs of submodule in vhdl project

Tags: vhdl, hdl, modelsim, xilinx-ise

I have build a cpu in vhdl. The cpu contains alu, ram, mux and other submodules. Now I want to dump all the values of inputs and outputs of submodules into csv or vcd files. I want to observe the changes for suppose 20 clock cycle. How can I do it in VHDL. I am using ModelSim for simulation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you do it? You read the user manual on "dumping"

Comment: The printing facility is textio.   So go to google and search on "using VHDL textio".   You will find many resources

Comment: I can store data using textio. But my problem is how can I get those data from submodules from top hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

Open a List Window in modelsim.  Add the signals you want to dump.  Run the sim.
File -> Write List -> Tabular.